# iOS 8 currentUserNotificationSettings return incorrect types

Tags: ios, ios8, remote-notifications

I am trying to detect the remote notification settings for the App in iOS 8

In case if app is installed, user disabled notifications, delete app and installed it again, this code return incorrect value:

```
- (BOOL)isRegisteredForRemoteNotification {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *noticationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
    NSUInteger types = noticationSettings.types;
    return types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
}
```

types in this case == 7 (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert), but in settings all notification types is disabled.

On OS higher then 8 all work fine. What's wrong?